# Como que se faz um menu deslizante em java?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Como que se faz um menu neste estilo aqui, que ao clicar ele oculta um conteúdo, e mostra outro?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algum exemplo de como se faz mais ou menos?

Algo tipo esse menu lateral desse site por exemplo

[www.altopadraocorretora.com.br](http://www.altopadraocorretora.com.br)

Comment: Cara a "lógica" é a mesma de um sistema de navegação por abas, vc encontra isso aos montes por ai, procure por Tab Navigation, ou Tab Component

Comment: Isso pode ser feito com Ajax

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Por favor. faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e leia o [Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt - Versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/13561)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie cada uma das pagina no mesmo local, mesmo nome. OBS: precisa de um servidor para rodar, só abri o arquivo com navegador não funciona. Se tiver o php no path so usar o comando no cmd "php -S localhost:3000" dentro da pasta onde os arquivos estao.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Requisições assíncronas</title>  
        <!-- bootstrap - link cdn -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <script>
            function requisitarPagina(url) {
                document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = ''
                
                //incluir o gif de loading na página
                if(!document.getElementById('loading')) {
                    let imgLoading = document.createElement('img')
                    imgLoading.id = 'loading'
                    imgLoading.src = 'loading.gif'
                    imgLoading.className = 'rounded mx-auto d-block'

                    document.getElementById('conteudo').appendChild(imgLoading)
                }

                let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

                //requisição não iniciada, state = 0
                //console.log(ajax.readyState)
                ajax.open('GET', url)

                //conexão estabelecida com o servidor, state = 1
                //console.log(ajax.readyState)
                

                //de alguma lógica que fique olhando para o progresso da req
                ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {

                        document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = ajax.responseText
                        //document.getElementById('loading').remove()
                    }

                    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 404) {

                        document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = '.. tente novamente mais tarde :s ..'
                        //document.getElementById('loading').remove()
                    }
                }
                ajax.send()
                //console.log(ajax)
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Static navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light mb-4">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">
                <h3>Requisições síncronas e assíncronas</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row mb-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm-2 mb-2">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="requisitarPagina('pagina_1.html')">Página 1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 mb-2">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="requisitarPagina('pagina_2.html')">Página 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 mb-2">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="requisitarPagina('pagina_3.html')">Página 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>

                <div class="col-md-10" id="conteudo"></div>
                    
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

pagina_1.html

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h4>PÁGINA 1</h4>
        <hr />

        <p>Lorem ipsum accumsan vulputate magna etiam nulla condimentum adipiscing, lectus sapien iaculis quisque cras ornare et viverra, vel metus interdum adipiscing ante condimentum leo. et fusce in non in senectus etiam, quisque conubia litora quis massa cursus, gravida justo nibh conubia vel. neque aenean integer viverra habitant fermentum ligula sed mollis taciti facilisis nullam blandit duis in commodo, faucibus pulvinar augue volutpat fringilla sagittis nostra blandit himenaeos augue risus fames ultrices. rhoncus volutpat etiam eleifend lorem eget sagittis viverra aliquam facilisis erat commodo ultricies, senectus curae sem rutrum pretium ut aptent ac imperdiet posuere diam, phasellus venenatis sem morbi nunc nulla cursus nullam vitae velit vulputate.</p>
        <p>Mollis elit libero potenti iaculis himenaeos curabitur ornare metus, vel rhoncus sociosqu eros interdum curabitur placerat scelerisque odio, amet venenatis curae posuere massa ante ut. quisque dui maecenas turpis dolor lobortis a velit aliquet purus, faucibus amet euismod habitasse inceptos urna proin massa proin curabitur, odio ante aenean dolor magna rhoncus pulvinar consectetur. habitasse ad pellentesque egestas taciti nullam tincidunt hac fringilla netus primis suspendisse, vestibulum nisi sit vitae rutrum convallis donec semper diam. imperdiet praesent magna faucibus est aliquam varius semper, dui auctor vulputate nunc aenean placerat, platea libero et in fringilla blandit.</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

pagina_2.html

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h4>PÁGINA 2</h4>

        <hr />

        <p>Curae nibh ipsum aptent urna augue neque facilisis enim tellus ornare ultrices, nisl metus ut etiam quisque mattis ipsum congue dolor himenaeos. non facilisis phasellus sodales pharetra maecenas fermentum, sapien metus justo elit nisi gravida vel, curabitur risus nunc ac gravida. sollicitudin vulputate mauris est augue id ornare elit, viverra ullamcorper maecenas feugiat cubilia convallis, viverra cras habitant hendrerit pretium fames. quisque suscipit tortor id morbi commodo sodales dolor cras imperdiet, lectus sapien dictum senectus himenaeos aptent congue magna sociosqu feugiat, fringilla fermentum felis sollicitudin aliquam ipsum elit cras.</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

pagina_3.html

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h4>PÁGINA 3</h4>

        <hr />

        <p>Condimentum platea cursus aptent odio tempor hac sit, hac interdum sociosqu lobortis adipiscing elit vitae, suscipit tristique dictum nullam donec venenatis. purus molestie velit habitant phasellus, class taciti ultricies risus tempor, porta viverra sagittis. curabitur interdum luctus phasellus vulputate viverra molestie at consectetur, justo dolor lectus iaculis quisque turpis a quam mi, dictum a varius blandit cursus volutpat hendrerit. amet aliquet neque praesent donec neque vehicula fusce, consectetur mi sed aliquam dictumst sem torquent, diam leo sapien pretium lectus sit. aliquet nibh aptent venenatis risus porta mi inceptos arcu massa felis, congue ornare phasellus ligula semper sapien varius etiam donec tempor litora, molestie mollis faucibus porttitor eu sociosqu maecenas ipsum viverra.</p>
        <p>Fermentum donec viverra curae vehicula netus donec libero odio nibh fusce, sollicitudin duis porta mattis cubilia arcu rutrum fringilla orci. ultrices laoreet semper augue malesuada elit congue odio venenatis dui velit, porta elementum himenaeos ac luctus justo vestibulum nec donec est quisque, consectetur viverra diam congue lorem aliquet mauris netus varius. justo consectetur ut nulla elit leo dictum non phasellus leo, vulputate nisl nostra tincidunt elit sapien malesuada sodales, facilisis mollis hac cursus conubia augue taciti bibendum. suspendisse dapibus libero nunc nulla vivamus non habitant integer semper turpis, vitae donec suspendisse venenatis sit est velit risus.</p>
        <p>Arcu aliquam id pharetra taciti sapien auctor egestas, netus id rhoncus aenean eros blandit et, hendrerit elementum mauris ligula accumsan dictum. amet class suspendisse adipiscing sit dui urna neque odio, adipiscing consectetur dui ultricies etiam porttitor vivamus, libero lobortis proin commodo rutrum facilisis aenean. praesent id etiam ullamcorper mollis sodales blandit cubilia ultrices, a volutpat aenean vel quisque phasellus rutrum morbi, nullam feugiat semper curae netus tempus orci. tristique ligula viverra morbi aliquet nisl bibendum, proin et diam urna consequat sed, sem aenean non vivamus quisque. pellentesque id arcu hac nec donec mauris, pharetra habitasse sed dictumst massa, fermentum adipiscing augue cras nulla.</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionou muito bem, eu tinha parado pra dar uma estudada no código e vi que realmente eu não tinha colocado o navbar. Muito obrigado amigo.